# What happens to constants in a .msg?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

If I have the following message:

```
uint8 val
uint8 a=0
uint32 b=0
string c=this is the string
```

Which I publish as follows:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "test_types/type33.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test_types_publisher_type33");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<test_types::type33>("/test_types/type33", 10);
  ros::Rate loop_rate(1);

  while (ros::ok())
  {
    test_types::type33 msg;
    msg.val=10;

    chatter_pub.publish(msg);
    ros::spinOnce();
    loop_rate.sleep();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However when I echo the topic or I check with wireshark, I only see `val` and the length of the messages in the header is also 1 byte: `01 00 00 00 0a`. So where are the constants transmitted?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370126/what-happens-to-constants-in-a-.msg?/) by [Ariel](https://answers.ros.org/users/23277/ariel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2021-01-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-23**:\

> ```
> string c=this is the string
> ```

is this a verbatim copy-paste? Because `string` constants should be enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> So where are the constants transmitted?

Nowhere (*).

They are *compile time* constants (in compiled languages such as C and C++) or predefined (constant) variables in the namespace of the message class / struct / dictionary for languages like Python. They are not part of the data that gets (de)serialised when exchanging messages.

So in your case, since you don't use `test_types::type33::a` or any of the other constants anywhere in your code, you'll not see their values anywhere in the serialised data stream.

It would also not be very efficient to do that for each and every message.

The assumption is that publisher and subscriber both have access to the message structure (ie: definition file or code generated from those). As the constants would be present in those representations, the receiving side can use them.

*) I wrote *nowhere*, but that's not exactly true. The complete message definition *is* exchanged between publisher and subscriber during setup of the connection, so technically the constant values are also sent to the subscriber.

But that's not as part of the actual message data exchange, hence the *nowhere*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4